# Что это за формат даты? 2017-12-17T19:44:46+03:00

Tags: php, дата

Вижу в АПИ которое я использую, принимает дату такого вида:

> 2017-12-17T19:44:46+03:00

А что это за формат такой? +03:00, T - это что?

Если мне на php вывести нужно текущую дату минус 1 час, как правильно выводить?

```
$startDate      = date('Y-m-d', time()-3600) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', time()-3600) . '+03:00';
```

Вот так выводить приходится, может есть какой-то более "красивый" способ? Может встроенная функция есть какая-то?

Comment: Это смещение зоны.

Comment: `echo date('c', strtotime('-1 hour', time()));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). `+03:00` — смещение зоны, которое зависит от часового пояса, на который настроен сервер, и текущей даты; `+03:00` это смещение для `Europe/Moscow` с 2014 года.

Вывести текущую дату минус один час:

```
echo date('c', time()-3600);
```

Результат:

```
2017-12-17T20:07:00+03:00
```

Comment: P.S. https://xkcd.ru/1179/

Answer (score 2):

> А что это за формат такой?

Как уже правильно сказали это стандарт ISO 8601, но имейте в виду, что в PHP `DateTime::ISO8601` вводит в заблуждение, если вас интересует этот стандарт следует использовать `DateTime::ATOM`. Подробнее вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.atom).

> Вот так выводить приходится, может есть какой-то более "красивый"
>   способ? Может встроенная функция есть какая-то?

Есть более красивый объектный поход:

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('utc')); //получение текущего времени по utc
$date->sub(new DateInterval('1H'); //Вычитаем один час
$startDate = $date->format(DateTime::ATOM); //Форматируем по ISO 8601
```

Если вам нужно время по москве, то замените `utc` на `Europe/Moscow`. Со списком всех временных зон вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php), но не используйте те константы что определены в классе `DateTimeZone`, это не сработает.