# Str to datetime учитывая часовой пояс

Tags: python-3.x

Привет всем. Есть вот такая строка:

```
s = '2017-07-12T20:08:35.083Z'
```

Как ее сконвертировать в объект datetime?

Comment: о каком часовом поясе идет речь?

Comment: @MaxU если внимательно посмотреть содержимое строки, то можно заметить, что часовой пояс указан :)

Comment: @andreymal, да, спасибо :)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что это за формат даты? 2017-12-17T19:44:46+03:00](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759659)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = '2017-07-12T20:08:35.083Z'    
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fz").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Если гугл решит прописывать другой часовой пояс, этот код сломается

Comment: наивный datetime объект может быть двусмысленным (часто местное время означает, что не имеет смысла для ответа с сервера). Можно вызвать `.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` чтобы часовую зону явно добавить.

Comment: @jfs , большое спасибо, буду знать :)

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
In [24]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [28]: parse('2017-07-12T20:08:35.083+0100')
Out[28]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 20, 8, 35, 83000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))

In [29]: parse('2017-07-12T20:08:35.083Z')
Out[29]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 20, 8, 35, 83000, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

PS следует установить `dateutil` если он еще не установлен:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Мне google апишкой отдает такую строку. Вот примеры: 'createTime': '2017-04-07T13:34:01.715Z', 'createTime': '2017-05-06T14:44:12.809Z'

Comment: Стоит отметить, что dateutil требует предварительной его установки

Comment: `pip install dateutil` → `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil`. Я специально оформил свой коммент так, чтобы вы попались :D

Comment: @andreymal, я пользуюсь `Anaconda` и мне эти проблемы незнакомы ... ;)

Comment: `dateutil` слишком много входных значений может разрешать (и пытаться угадать результат). Если разрешённый формат фиксирован, то более строгие парсеры лучше использовать.

Answer (score 1):

В своё время я не нашёл встроенных решений, позволяющих парсить ISO 8601 с часовым поясом без лишней возни, поэтому предлагаю установить [iso8601](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601):

```
>>> import iso8601

>>> iso8601.parse_date('2017-07-12T20:08:35.083Z')
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 20, 8, 35, 83000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> iso8601.parse_date('2017-07-12T23:08:35.083+03:00')
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 23, 8, 35, 83000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 10800), '+03:00'))
```

Также может понадобиться преобразовать локальные датувремя в UTC:

```
>>> date = iso8601.parse_date('2017-07-12T23:08:35.083+03:00')
>>> date.replace(tzinfo=None) - date.utcoffset()
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 12, 20, 8, 35, 83000)
```